# Handle message from another thread in Win32 windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, event-handling, win32gui

I created a window with Win32s, I wish it could handle incoming messages from another thread in addition to typical windows messages.

I'm using this piece of code:

```
 while (dataAvailable || GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) 
    {
       // if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        if (dataAvailable == true)
        {
            cout << "My thread message/signal!" << endl;
            dataAvailable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Windows message
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

the "DataAvailable" is an atomic bool that I set when I would like pass a my own message to win32 app/windows.

This don't work well.

It is possible to do this?

Comment: From the background thread send a message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user) to the thread (the one that has the message pump) using PostMessage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea). You might need to pass the HWND from the thread to the backgroundthread so it knows where to send the messages to. I know it isn't the fastest way to respond, but in practice you will always deal with extra latency when using message queues

Comment: Another option is to run a message pump based on [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects). This function waits until a message arrives or one or more kernel objects (e.g. events, see `CreateEvent`) become signaled, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use standard messages. Register your own new message and use PostMessage from another thread to your main window thread.

I base my example code on standard windows sample code: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/begin/LearnWin32/HelloWorld/cpp/main.cpp

In this code I add a standard std::thread :

```
// ... 

  auto th1 = std::thread([=] {
    const UINT WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE = ::RegisterWindowMessage(L"SomeSpecialInternalMessage");
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
      PostMessage(hwnd, WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE, 0, 0);
      Sleep(1000);
    }
  });

  // Run the message loop.
  MSG msg = { };
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  th1.join();
```

As you see in this code, `WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE` is a custom windows message. Its posted every second to you main window proc: WindowProc. To receive it modify WindowProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  const UINT WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE = ::RegisterWindowMessage(L"SomeSpecialInternalMessage");

  if(uMsg == WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE) {
    OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_EX_SOME_SPECIALINTERNALMESSAGE\n");
  }
  
  // ...
```